# Probability Cumulative distribution function for exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, functions, random-variables, exponential-function

what is the probability Cumulative distribution function for exponential distribution?

I searched the web a lot but it was strange that no answers were found.

I know that F(t) is the integral of f(t) which means $F(t)=-e^{ \lambda  *t}/{ \lambda}$ is this right?

Comment: Or the integral should be closed from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: I am getting a lot of contradictions since F(t) should be positive function...

Comment: Good luck on your studies Daniel.

Comment: Morris H DeGroot_ Mark J Schervish - Probability and statistics-Pearson Education (2012), page 321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be found in any elementary probability textbook, but anyway:

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt = \begin{cases} 0 & x \leq 0 \\ \int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt = 1-e^{-\lambda x} & x>0 \end{cases}.$$

Note that there is the $\lambda$ factor on the outside of the PDF. This is a normalization factor, since just $e^{-\lambda x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ isn't normalized unless $\lambda=1$.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the integral as the result is what u wrote multiplied by $1/ \lambda$

Comment: @daniel No, it's correct. As I said in the second paragraph, you need a $\lambda$ in front to normalize everything.

Comment: integral of $\lambda e^{- \lambda * t}$ is $-e^{- \lambda * t} / \lambda$

Comment: No it isn't. It's $\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda t}}{-\lambda}=-e^{-\lambda t}$. Now this is a negative function, which looks problematic if you aren't thinking carefully. But because it is an *increasing* negative function, you get a positive result out of it when you plug in bounds and subtract.